# Audio randomly pausing on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I have a recently developed a strange problem with my iPhone 4S. If I start playing audio (the two apps I've noticed this problem with are [RSSRadio7](http://www.doradasoftware.com/) and [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/), although I assume it affects other audio-based apps too), approximately 50% of the time the audio stops (it quickly fades out and the phone "pauses" it) after about 1-2 minutes, although the exact time period seems to be random. Sometimes it happens almost straight away. Sometimes it seems to happen when I put it in my pocket, sometimes when it's on the desk. I'm confident that I'm not touching any buttons or the screen. If I turn the phone on, I can see on the homescreen that the audio is paused, and if I hit "play" it continues, although sometimes it then pauses again shortly afterward in the same time. This never used to happen (started a month or so ago, I've been using the phone and those apps for years).

I'd love to hear if there are any potential software causes, as then I could investigate and come up with a workaround.

- I can't think of anything significant I've changed recently, settings-wise
- I can’t imagine a hardware fault which might cause this

What could be causing this?

Comment: It looks like a connectivity issue, and it's easily testable. Try any other audio app which's content is not *streamed* and see if it happens there too.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this is a connectivity issue. In both cases the content is cached; Spotify cached playlists and downloaded podcasts in RSSRadio7. This issue has also happened when the device has been in airplane mode.